# How can I calculate the growth of a small creature using a DSLR?

Tags: trigonometry

I have a science project idea to complete in which I intend to grow brine shrimp and collect their growth data.

I am planning to photograph these creatures daily from a set height using a clamp. I will take images from above their open topped tank to prevent distortion.

However, I am unsure as to how exactly I am to calculate the growth from these images taken. Perhaps I could use trigonometry? Although, I am unsure how to use it in this way.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to measure length from a photograph? You need a reference of known length in the photograph to be able to do that. Something like a strip of paper of which you know it's 1cm in length in real life. The reference should be on the same plane as the shrimp too if your picture is taken from above.

If you need to be very precise, you'll need to think of a different measurement method.

Comment: It would help if you could persuade the shrimp to pose for the picture, straightening out and orienting themselves perpendicular to the camera.  That's not likely to happen, though.  But if you have a reasonably large number of shrimp, it's likely that enough of them will be nearly perpendicular to the camera that the measured size will be close to the real size.